# Filtering optimization problem

Tags: combinatorial-optimization

First, let me give you some background. I develop embedded software and I have a filtering problem where I think I could use some help from mathematicians.

I have a filtering table which has the following functionalities:

- possible 100 entries
- 50 entries support exact match filtering
- 50 entries support range match filtering

Since we are talking about embedded software, range filtering is in terms of bits. That means I can filter in ranges in base 2. This part cannot be changed.
For example:

- numbers from 0-1 (1 bit)
- numbers from 0-3 (2 bits)
- numbers from 0-7 (3 bits)
- numbers from 0-15 (4 bits)
  ...

Now comes the problem that I have. If I assume that I have random 70 numbers what would be the most optimal way or arranging those?

In reality, we talk about 32bit numbers, but for simplicity let's focus on numbers up to 1000.

One example would be if I have numbers 1, 5, 565. One solution would be to add these to exact filters since I have only 3 of them.

Another example is that I have number 0,1,2,9,565. I can add all of them to exact filters.
Another approach is that I add 0,1,2 to range filter and only after check that I did not get a "false" positive (number 3). The rest can go to exact filters.

As you can see the problems are not trivial once we go to higher numbers. I would like to define a cost function for myself, but I do not know how to set it up properly.

The most important param is that all numbers are inside the filter.
The second one is that I use the maximum num of exact filters. 
The third one is that I have range filters where I need to have as least overhead as possible after the filter says I have a match.

The reason for these "weights" is that this part is performance-critical. It will be done many times and after this step, I would like to have the smallest number of steps possible to determine if the number was in the filters or not.

Comment: It would help for the range filtering if you could filter on other sets of bits. Say odds from 0 to 15, so that I only need three bits to look at. Do the range filters have this capability?  In general you have to express one of 2**(2**32) possible subsets with only 100 limited expressions, and my feeling is that you need more.  A good test would be filtering the set of Fibonnaci numbers. Gerhard "Or Another Very Sparse Sequence" Paseman, 2019.11.13.

Comment: Actually, I see now that you need to trap only 70 numbers. In that case you have enough expressions, and the idea is to arrange the tests how? So that the first failure specifies the trapped number? Or that all filtered numbers pass one of the tests?  Gerhard "Is Throwing Out Bath Water?" Paseman, 2019.11.13.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Yes, that is the reason I limited myself to 70 elements.

To answer your second question, it is possible to play with bits as well, but it only adds to the complexity. For example, if you have the following 4-bit filter, it is possible to set bits 2 or 3 to matching bits and rest to don't care, but as I said would probably add to more complexity then.


The idea is that my filter needs to tell me if it found a match or not.

I am trying to come up with a function that tells me how good the filter is. Something like a cost function.

Comment: Then I would be able to write an optimization algorithm that would try to minimize this, but still within limits that I said.

As said the input can be any number withing the range, and then the filter does his matching and tells me if there is a match in any entry.

Comment: One thing that crosses my mind is to have a couple of set tasks such as fill exact filters until there are none. Find groups in terms of odd/even numbers and so on.
After that, I could just do some magic such as genetic algorithms to try and "poke" a local minimum.
But in order to do this, I still need a cost function.
Also, this approach seems "hacky" and specialized. What if the filter changes so that there are other rules.

I am looking for a more generic solution. Any books/articles on this topic would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This reminds me of Knuth's BDD's. (He did not invent binary decision diagrams, but he has written about them.) If for each (numbered) test, you were allowed to jump to a different numbered test depending on outcome, then cost of a critical path or longest path in a (loop less) BDD with weighted nodes would sound like a good metric to me. Gerhard "Got To Watch Those Microseconds" Paseman, 2019.11.14.